# On localhost it runs perfectly but online gives the warning Curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in

Tags: javascript, php, curl, localhost, web-hosting

On my localhost, it runs perfectly, but on my web host, I got the following error.

> PHP Warning:  curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in \WINDOWSxxxx.LOCAWEB.COM.BR\xxxx\xxxxx\pagamento.php on line 15, 16, 18 and 19

I don't know if this is a syntax error?

```
<?php

    include 'config.php';
    //session_start();
    #create the request
    $url = URL_PAGSEGURO."sessions?email=".EMAIL_PAGSEGURO."&token=".TOKEN_PAGSEGURO;

    //http://br2.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-setopt.php

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, true);

    $retorno = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($retorno);
    echo json_encode($xml);
```

Comment: Please include what other posts you have read to search for the solution before you posted this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to using curl on PHP (please don't judge to harsh) and found this to be more user friendly, less typing.. I hope that it will help. I didn't include all of your parameters, this is just to show you another way.

```
$curl = curl_init();

$apiURL; // This will have to be set
$data; // This will have to be set

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POST=>true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true;
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'x-api-key: nPwrkTQyjW7DnFdvU='
    )
));

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
curl_close($curl);
```